# One column various data combinations instead of multiple data columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, benchmarking

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE type_a1=1 AND type_a2=5 AND type_b2=8
```

Such command can be found in normal cases. But assuming 1 special case where:

- Each **user** has 260 **types** (a0, b0..z0 to a9, b9..z9),
- Each **type** also has 10 **values** from 0-9.

In the special case, there exist a requirement for the combination of 260 types to be specified. Instead of using 260 SELECTs on 260 columns, I want to use 1 single column so that the command would look like this

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE type='a04b05c01...y95z96'
```

My question is twofold:

1) Is it more effective to use 1 single column like that to store multiple data combinations instead of several columns?

2) If (sometimes) the requirement is **Only** to select a combination of 3 types (other 257 types can be whatever), how is the performance of our 1st command in the case of 260 columns of user types, comparing to the command below in the case of 1 single column of user types?

```
SELECT name... FROM users WHERE type LIKE %a11% AND type LIKE %a25% AND type LIKE %b281%
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement this as an [EAV data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) where the users would be your entities and the types would be your attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. There are different opinions around implementing EAV, so I'd hesitate to apply it in my real work case.